# How can I specify the character encoding to be used by OLEDB when querying a DBF?

Tags: .net, ado.net, character-encoding, oledb, dbf

Is it possible to specify which character encoding should be used by OLEDB when querying a DBF file?

A possible work-around would be to encode the query string before the OLEDB call to the DBF file's character encoding and then encode all the results when they are returned. This will work but it would be nice if OLEDB or possibly ADO.NET could do this for me.

**UPDATE**

The [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475821/how-can-i-specify-the-character-encoding-to-be-used-by-oledb-when-querying-a-dbf/1475862#1475862) by Viktor Jevdokimov does not seem to work automatically. But it made me investigate manual conversion of the strings. It is possible to use the TextInfo property of CultureInfo to find out the OemCodePage and the WindowsCodePage and use those to get the corresponding Encoding instances to perform manual conversion. But I can not get ADO.NET use these encondings to perform the conversion for me.

Comment: Probably because ADO.NET is a transport and encoding conversion belongs somewhere else, where the transformation occurs, like reading with Reader or writing with Writer or any other I/O.

Comment: How then would your answer provide a solution for me? I do not get it :)

Comment: The thread is in your app level. You change thread culture before calling ADO.NET - this will convert your strings to appropriate encoding to and from ADO.NET. You restore original thread encoding for your other input/output. Have you tried my method?

Answer (score 2):

Before executing DBF SQL I change CurrentThread's CurrentCulture and restore thereafter:

```
Dim appCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
//execute command here
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = appCulture
```

Comment: How will the thread culture affect the character encoding? There is a TextInfo property of the CultureInfo but it only deals with code pages.

Comment: Let say your current runtime culture is Unicode or UTF-8 or any else. .NET will convert everything coming to it to Unicode to store internally in memory and convert back using current culture when outputing. So changing current thread culture says to .NET how to do conversions for input/output.