# Vb.net, DBF file, cannot set numeric size (always 20.5)

Tags: numeric, foxpro, dbf

I create DBF files using JET oleDb 4.0, but the numeric fields always end up being (20.5) size. This is a known problem from what I read on the net. Many people are suggesting to use the Visual FoxPro oleDb which I tried, but I need to open the DBF files in ArcMap and I get errors about incorrect field types. I guess that the file format is not supported. If I open a DBF created with the FoxPro oledb in FoxPro and I export it in DBase IV format, then I can open it in ArcMap.

But when I create it, I already use the "Extended Properties=dBase IV" option, and it does not seems to do anything at all.

I have to find a way to get the correct field sizes in DBASE IV format. Can someone help me?

Here is my connection strings:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=dBase IV;
Which makes always makes numeric in 20.5 size

Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source={0};Collating Sequence=general;Extended Properties=dBase IV;
Which makes incompatible DBF for ArcMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer for encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054907/oledb-custom-encoding/26102836#26102836)

It uses the VFP OleDB provider, just ignore the context of the CODEPAGE references.  The create table syntax will be similar and you can define your numeric fields as needed.  The next critical part is the use of the VFPScript in the section...

```
  string vfpScript = @"use MyTest1
            Copy to MyTest2 type foxplus";


   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command.CommandText = "ExecScript";
   command.Parameters.Add("myScript", OleDbType.Char).Value = vfpScript;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This takes the .dbf file from a VFP normal file header to a dBASE compatible (early FoxPro) file header which SHOULD be compatible with what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I only have another little problem which is that the fields can not contains null values. But I only had to change my code to insert something else than null values and it works well.

Comment: @Math, for older dBASE, I don't recall if it allows for NULL vs NOT NULL, but you could always TRY adding after the respective column(s) in the create table statement.

Comment: I tried and it does not work. You are right about older dBASE files not allowing null settings. But I don't need it anymore since I removed the nulls inserts. Thanks!