# The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine exceptions persists

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, foxpro

**Please read remark below:**

I'm trying to connect to a fox pro database and it is very frustrating.

Following some of the answers in StackOverflow, I did the following:

- Installed the vfpoledb from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)
- I sat the platform target to x86 in the project properties.
- Ran Visual Studio/Application in Administrator mode
- Database file is unblocked.

It still throws an exception that the provider is not registered on this machine.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro X64 and Visual Studio Community 2017.

```
 public class FoxProHandler
    {
        static OleDbConnection connector = default(OleDbConnection);
        static bool isConnected = false;
        public static string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
        private FoxProHandler()
        {

        }

        public static void SetConnectionString(string Value)
        {
            ConnectionString = Value;
        }
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetValues(string PartNumberValue, Dictionary<string, string> Mapper)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        public static void Connect()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConnectionString))
            {
                throw new Exception("Connection string is empty");
            }
            if (isConnected == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CREATING DB CONNECTOR");
                    connector = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
                    Console.WriteLine($"CREATING DB CONNECTOR OBJECT");                 
                    connector.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine($"OPENED CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY");
                    isConnected = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message} {e.StackTrace}"); 
                }

            }

        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Amen\Downloads", "ADMQH20X.DBC"); 
           string connectionString = $"Provider=\"VFPOLEDB\";Data Source=\"{fileName}\";Collate=Machine;"; 
           FoxProHandler.SetConnectionString(connectionString);
           FoxProHandler.Connect();
           Console.ReadKey(); 

        }
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Remark:**
After procuring the necessary files (.dbf), the application still throws an exception during a debug session but not when running the application from explorer.

Comment: I was trying to say I set the platform target to x86 in the project properties.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you see anything wrong? What do you mean by document the connection string?

Comment: Provider is VFPOLEDB not "VFPOLEDB". I will gave a sample soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please test this code (provided you have or created c:\temp):

```
void Main()
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry this is not going to work in 64 bits");
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable tbl=new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\Temp"))
        {
            con.Open();
            new OleDbCommand("create table myTest (id int, dummy c(10))",con).ExecuteNonQuery();
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into myTest (id, dummy) values (?,?)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Integer);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("dum", OleDbType.VarChar,10);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = i + 1;
                cmd.Parameters["dum"].Value = $"Dummy#{i+1}";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            tbl.Load(new OleDbCommand("select * from myTest",con).ExecuteReader());
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(int)row["id"]} : {(string)row["Dummy"]}");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or if you edit in Notepad and compile with csc:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace Test
{
  class Test
  {

static void Main()
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry this is not going to work in 64 bits");
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable tbl=new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\Temp"))
        {
            con.Open();
            new OleDbCommand("create table myTest (id int, dummy c(10))",con).ExecuteNonQuery();
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into myTest (id, dummy) values (?,?)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Integer);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("dum", OleDbType.VarChar,10);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = i + 1;
                cmd.Parameters["dum"].Value = $"Dummy#{i+1}";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            tbl.Load(new OleDbCommand("select * from myTest",con).ExecuteReader());
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(int)row["id"]} : {(string)row["Dummy"]}");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

}
}
```

Save it, say VFPOLEDBTest.cs and compile with:

```
csc VFPOLEDBTest.cs /platform:x86
```

and run:

```
VFPOLEDBTest.exe
```

Output:

```
d:\Academy>VFPOLEDBTest.exe
1 : Dummy#1
2 : Dummy#2
3 : Dummy#3
4 : Dummy#4
5 : Dummy#5
6 : Dummy#6
7 : Dummy#7
8 : Dummy#8
9 : Dummy#9
10 : Dummy#10
```

Comment: Same error. Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

you try with: **build as x86**, run command in cmd **regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\vfpoledb.dll"** (installed vpf driver)

Comment: tip: Run it as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple indeed, you had extra quotes in connection string that is causing the problem:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Amen\Downloads", "ADMQH20X.DBC"); 
           string connectionString = $"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source={fileName}";
           DataTable tbl = new DataTable(); 
           using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
           using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from myTable", con))
           {
              con.Open();
              tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
           }

           // do Something with datatable
        }
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.' Your code throws the same exception.

Comment: @AmenJLILI, then you didn't install the VFPOLEDB correctly or not using x86. Try testing your code in Linqpad (LinqPad default install is 32 bits if you don't choose AnyCPU). Or maybe you edited the code I sent more than just editing the table name.

Comment: I have installed the driver from this link here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839 and have the target platform to x86. It throws the exception when it tries to open the connection.

Comment: @AmenJLILI, did you try the code in LinqPad? We can check online using team viewer if you like to. You could also test the provider with VBA say from within Excel. I am not really sure you are trying in 32 bits.

Comment: Do you mind if we exchange emails? I have really to show this.

Comment: @AmenJLILI. that is fine. cetinbasoz @ gmail com Actually I sent one to your email address that I found here yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

[From another answer on VFP and OleDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054907/oledb-custom-encoding/26102836#26102836)

A few things... The provider is "VFPOLEDB.1"
Second, the connection string should point to a PATH, not the specific table.
Finally, once you have a PATH connection, you can query from any SUB-PATH/FOLDER
within that.

```
var connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=c:\\YourDataPath\\SomeSubFolder;";
```

Then your queries can be as simple as

```
select YT.* from YourTable YT where...
```

and if you have sub-folders, you can do...

```
select YT.* 
    from 
       YourTable YT
         JOIN AnotherSubFolder\SomeOtherTable SOT
            on YT.SomeKey = SOT.SomeKey
    where...
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'VFPOLEDB.1' provider is not registered on the local machine.' I think it is something that I am unable to figure out...

Comment: The provider is "VFPOLEDB", and the connection string can either point to a path or the fully qualified name of a database file (DBC).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, You are correct on pointing to the .DBC.  However, I have had instances of trying to use VFPOLEDB and failed, but VFPOLDDB.1 (for whatever reason) worked.  That is what I have historically used without issue for years.

Comment: OK. In this case the reason was not VFPOLEDB nor the connection string itself. It was failing in existing project in VS (reason?). It worked compiling another test (above test code namely). In the given path files were missing anyway (no tables and only .DBC).